# Switching from ExtJS3 to ExtJS4: Worth the hassle?

Tags: migration, extjs4, extjs3

We are in the middle of a relatively large project which uses ExtJS3 and have already invested ~4 man-years, using several plugins and we have written some plugins ourselfs. After a quick glance at ExtJS4, it seems that we would have a lot of work to do to migrate the project to ExtJS4. Are there any strong reasons to switch to ExtJS4? Currently, it seems to me that compatibility with future browsers (or the lack thereof) is the only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're in similar situation and our conclusion was to wait a bit more as Ext 3 is doing it's job. We experienced many problems in our "test" migration and I would say that it's more a rewrite of the application than a migration :(. Also, our experience showed that Ext JS 4 has some performance problems, forms are a bit different, store cannot reject changes, it's bigger. There are some very good new features like the new class system, mixins, new charts, ...

Comment: After a week of evaluation, we also have decided to stay with Ext3, since Ext4 seems slower and buggy with the kind of layout we have.

Answer (score 2):

We have upgraded our application to ExtJS4 without fail.We are happy to say that ExtJS4 is fast compare to ExtJS3.A new class system,mixins,plugin-free charts,focus management...etc.,. But if you want to upgrade you need to change a lot of code because class system and config options are changed.We have tested the performance of our application using ExtJS3 and ExtJS4,so as per our observation ExtJS4 is fast and it will not break.As per our observation,CSS selectors are also changed if you want to customize the component you can easily do the thing in ExtJS4.

Comment: You asked 15 questions about Ext 4 problems on SO and then said that migration went without hassle :)

Comment: Yes but at last we are succeded with the help of people in stackoverflow.If its 15 questions you have to think about project wise :)

Answer (score 1):

We tried to migrate from ExtJS3 to ExtJS4 previous week. Unfortunately I must say it is like translate english to german. A lot of work. From our point of view more or less just the charting system is plus, minus - a lot of components that we use are not supported, a lot of css customization shoud be done, working code in ExtJS3 breaks easily and there is sometimes almost impossible to find an error.

Comment: The new charting system in Ext4... well, we looked at it, but it's fscking slow compared to flot, so we stayed with flot (which plays well with Ext3, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but personally I'd start new project with extjs4 but leave exiting project alone. The charting stuff is amazing in 4!

Comment: We testet ExtJS4's charting, but in our tests it was a lot slower than Flot, so we kept Flot and had one less reason to switch.

Comment: Flot is nice. For my project the ability to combine the class/data model as well as Ext.direct seals the deal for me. Yup! I'm a fanboy...